# $\omega_{\alpha+1}$ is a projection of $\wp(\omega_{\alpha})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

some classmates and I are attacking this problem, which is exercise 3.10 of Jech's "Set theory" book:

$\omega_{\alpha+1}$ is a projection of $\wp(\omega_{\alpha})$

So, we need to find an onto function from $\wp({\omega_{\alpha}})$ to $\omega_{\alpha+1}$. We know that $|\omega_{\alpha}\times\omega_{\alpha}|=\omega_{\alpha}$, therefore we search for a surjective function from $\wp(\omega_{\alpha}\times\omega_{\alpha})$ to $\omega_{\alpha+1}$.

The book's hint goes as follows: "if $R\subseteq\omega_{\alpha}\times\omega_{\alpha}$ is a well-order, let $f(R)$ be its order type". However we can't have a good idea about how to proceed. Can anyone please help us?

Comment: Not sure of a proof, but conceptually this is trivial, since the power set of anything has greater cardinality than the original set.

Comment: @Alan The OP is not asking for a surjection from $\mathcal P(\omega_\alpha)$ to  the "original set" $\omega_\alpha,$ he wants a surjection from $\mathcal P(\omega_\alpha)$ to $\omega_{\alpha+1}.$ Also, I think he wants it done in set theory without the axiom of choice.

Comment: @bof I thought by definition,  $\omega _{\alpha + 1}$ was the next larger cardinal?   And since the power set has to be a larger cardinal, it's greater than or equal to the next one.  Again, not at all a proof of the actual surjection, since it's been over a year since my formal Set theory class

Comment: @Alan I'm guessing your set theory class didn't spend much time on the weirdness that can occur if you throw out the Axiom of Choice. $\omega_\alpha$ is the next larger cardinal **among the alephs**, i.e. the cardinals of well-orderable sets. If AC is false, there are sets that can't be well-ordered; their cardinalities are not alephs and are **imcomparable** with sufficiently large alephs. For example $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be **incomparable** with $\aleph_1.$ In such a case, there is **no injection** from $\omega_1$ to $\mathcal P(\omega)$, but there's still a surjection in the other direction.

Comment: @bof Ahh, yes, we only briefly covered some of that weirdness.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Alan Oops, can't edit that comment any more, but $\omega_\alpha$ was supposed to be $\omega_{\alpha+1}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourselves, what are the elements of $\omega_{\alpha+1}$? These are ordinals whose cardinality is at most $\aleph_\alpha$. Therefore each such ordinal has an injection into $\omega_\alpha$.

So for each $\eta<\omega_{\alpha+1}$, there is some $R\subseteq\omega_\alpha\times\omega_\alpha$ which is a well-ordering of its field (domain and range) with order type $\eta$.

Comment: thank you very much! Only some clarifications: by saying that you are just showing that the function $f: \wp(\omega_`\alpha}\cross\omega_{\alpha}` \omega_{\alpha + 1}$

Comment: thank you very much! Only some clarifications: by saying that you are just showing that the function $f: \wp(\omega_\alpha}\cross\omega_{\alpha}) \arrow \omega_{\alpha + 1}$  is surjective, aren't you?

Comment: Yes. That is what I do, from there you should be able to finish with what you already know.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why is $R\subset \omega_\alpha\times \omega_\alpha$ but not $R\subset \omega_\alpha$?

Comment: @Ander: Because it's a relation?