# Jech Set Theory 3rd Edition Ex 3.10

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

This question is a follow-up on [this question on Exercise 3.10 from Jech's Set Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964957/omega-alpha1-is-a-projection-of-wp-omega-alpha).

Given the hint, I understand that we seek a surjection from the subsets of $\omega_\alpha \times \omega_\alpha$ that are well-orderings to $\omega_{\alpha + 1}$. Asaf's answers in the linked question appears to provide such a surjection, but unfortunately I am not quite able to follow it. In particular, I cannot make sense of

> So for each $\eta<\omega_{\alpha+1}$, there is some $R\subseteq\omega_\alpha\times\omega_\alpha$ which is a well-ordering of its field (domain and range) with order type $\eta$.

How, given a map $f_\eta: \eta \to \omega_\alpha$, is $R$ derived? And according to which well-order (I assume the canonical one?) on $\text{Ord} \times \text{Ord}$ is its order type $\eta$?

I would appreciate an elaboration on the quoted answer, in particular concerning the questions raised above.

Edit: (If relevant) I am doing self-studies in Set Theory following Jech's book and I am currently stuck at this question.

Comment: This is not as hard as you’re making it. The ordering on $\eta$ induces an ordering on its image in $\omega_\alpha$ under the injection. $R$ is this ordering, which is by its definition isomorphic to $\eta.$

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I believe I have pinned down the source of my confusion: Regarding the last part of your final sentence, "... by its definition isomorphic to $\eta$.", I fail to see how. Let's have $R$ as defined by Shervin below (indeed, I see it is a WO on $\omega_\alpha$), what is the isomorphism (let's call it $g$) between $R$ and $\eta$? For instance, what is $g((\beta, \gamma))$?

Comment: $R$ is an ordering relation, not an ordered set, i.e. $(im(f),R)$ is an isomorphic order to $(\eta,\in).$ (Where $f$ is the injection $\eta\to \omega_\alpha.$) That help?

Comment: (I’m guessing that’s your misconception since you’re asking me what some *pair* maps to under the isomorphism.)

Comment: A binary relation on a set $S$ is some (any) subset of $S\times S.$  If $<_{\eta}$ is a binary relation  on $ \eta,$ then we write $x<_{\eta} y$ to mean $(x,y)\in <_{\eta}\subset  \eta \times \eta.$

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me so long. I think I have resolved my issue. I was aware of the isomorphic relationship between the two orders but concerned whether there might be some $\eta' \neq \eta$ s.t. $(im(f_{\eta'}), R_{\eta'}) \simeq (\eta, \in)$. But that would of course imply $\eta \simeq \eta'$ which cannot be. Hence there is indeed an onto mapping from the WOs on $\omega_\alpha$ to $\omega_{\alpha + 1}$. Set Theory is a fascinating subject but I have a feeling I might rely on you guys again at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an injection $f:\eta \rightarrow \omega_\alpha$, define $R$ to be $R = \{(\alpha , \beta) \in ran(f)×ran(f): f^{-1}(\alpha) \lt f^{-1}(\beta)\}$. Now you can easily check that $R$ is a well-order on its field.

Comment: This answer fit in well with spaceisdarkgreen's comments. Thank you for this input.